What is the general term for terms that end in -ian, -ist etc.?
All the terms with a definition starting with 'One who... ', what is the term to describe these terms?
Like, Occupation is the general term for a particular line of work; Mechanic, Doctor, Dentist, Librarian etc.

What is your Occupation?
Mechanic

Like, Profession is the general term for to describe professionalized occupations.

What is your Profession?
Psychiatrist.

Like, Discipline is the term for terms used to describe fields of study or work; Physics, Biology, Botany, Medicine, Acting etc.

What is your Discipline? OR Which Discipline are you from?
Physics.

Similarly, what is the term that is used to describe terms which describe persons who study, or practice, or work with (some particular thing)? Basically, those terms that end in -ian, -ist -ast, etc. What are the called? Does such a term exist at all? I feel like I have come across one, but can't find anything on google.

"Term for terms" doesn't make sense.  'Occupation' is the general term for the type of work a person does. (Not for a worker.)

@KateBunting You're right. With Occupation and Profession, it doesn't make sense. Edited accordingly. However, I would argue that with Discipline 'term for terms' has been used correctly and makes sense. Thoughts?

Why should that one be different? It's like saying 'the name of names of XXX'.

@KateBunting They are talking about the name of the grammatical term for a group of occupational terms that seem to be linguistically similar. Perfectly valid question in my opinion.

There is a related term, but it may be too hypernymic (semantically broad) for your purposes. And paradoxically, the definition, involving a distinct morphological definition of the term, may discount some words you wish to be included.
From Wikipedia:

Agent noun
Not to be confused with agent (grammar).
In linguistics, an agent noun (in Latin, nomen agentis) is a word that
is derived from another word denoting an action, and that identifies
an entity that does that action. For example, driver is an agent
noun formed from the verb drive.
Usually, 'derived' in the above definition has the strict sense
attached to it in morphology, that is the derivation takes as an input
a lexeme (an abstract unit of morphological analysis) and produces a
new lexeme. However, the classification of morphemes into derivational
morphemes  and inflectional ones is not generally a straightforward
theoretical question, and different authors can make different
decisions as to the general theoretical principles of the
classification as well as to the actual classification of morphemes
presented in a grammar of some language (for example, of the agent
noun-forming morpheme).
An agentive suffix (or an agentive prefix) is commonly used to form an
agent noun from a verb. Examples of such suffixes:
English: -er, -or, -ian, -ist


give → giver
constrict → constrictor
theory/theorise → theoretician*
rape → rapist

*There are many nouns especially with the suffix -ian clearly not derived from another word denoting an action:
physicist / beautician / historian / mathematician / proletarian [n] / equestrian [n] ...
However, many of these do specify  workers who work or participate in a particular line of work, profession, field of study, association (eg Rotarian), or religion, as well as those simply typically engaging in some activity (eg fetishist).
